# Loop through elements and parse them whith DOMDocument() in PHP

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I've a list of item like this:

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="ui_checkbox type hidden" data-categories="57 48 ">
        <input id="attraction_type_119" type="checkbox" value="119"
        <label for="attraction_type_119">Aquariums</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui_checkbox type " data-categories="47 ">
        <input id="attraction_type_120" type="checkbox" value="120"
        <label for="attraction_type_120">Arènes et stades</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I loop through them with `DOMDocument` to get details like:

- data-categories
- input value
- label text

This is what I tried:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
$data = array();
foreach($elements as $node){
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $data['data_categorie'] = $child->item(0)->getAttribute('data_categories');
        $data['input_value'] = $child->item(0)->getAttribute('input_value');
        $data['label_text'] = $child->item(0)->getAttribute('label_text');
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

What I'm missing here please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting multiple values in the loop like this `$data['data_categorie'] =` using the same key for the array `$data = array();` will overwrite the values on every iteration.

As you have multiple items, you could create a temporary array `$temp = [];` to store the values and add the array to the `$data` array after storing all the values for the current iteration.

As you are already using [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), you could get the div with *class="list"* using an expression like `//div[@class="list"]/div` and loop the childNodes checking for nodeName *input* and get that value plus the value of the next sibling which is the value of the *label*

```
$data = array();
$xp = new DOMXpath($dom);
$items = $xp->query('//div[@class="list"]/div');
foreach($items as $item) {
    $temp["data_categorie"] = $item->getAttribute("data-categories");
    foreach ($item->childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeName === "input") {
            $temp["input_value"] = $child->getAttribute("value");
            $temp["label_text"] = $child->nextSibling->nodeValue;
        }
    }
    $data[] = $temp;
}

print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data_categorie] => 57 48 
            [input_value] => 119
            [label_text] => Aquariums

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data_categorie] => 47 
            [input_value] => 120
            [label_text] => ArÃ¨nes et stades

        )

)
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/6ieof)

Answer (score 0):

I used `string()` and `evaluate` to get result in a single query:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "ui_checkbox")]');
foreach($elements as $node) {
    $data = array();
    $data['data_categorie'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(./@data-categories)', $node);
    $data['input_value'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(./input/@value)', $node);
    $data['label_text'] = $xpath->evaluate('string(./label/text())', $node);
}
```